# How do I select a field from a table where I am looking up the fieldname from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Doing some ETL and I have a wide file with lots of cols, for each different value.  I am trying to transform this into a vertical text file with one row per value item.
So my data table looks like;

```
Store  Date  Col1 Col2 Col3 ...
Store1 1/2/12 12   23   34  ...
Store2 1/2/12 23   34   35  ...
```

My Col lookup table looks like;

```
GLCode GLDesc TaxRate XLSColName
00.1234 Cash  0.00    Col2
```

So in my output file line I need;
`Store1,1/2/34,00.1234,0.00,23` 

where 23 is the value from the Data table in the Col2 field which was specificed in teh GL Lookup field.

I have been trying to do this is SQL as part of an SSIS package, as I could not see how to do it with the Lookup task, but cannot seem to do it in SQL either !!

Hope that makes sense and thanks for your help ! JK

Comment: Does it need to be entirely dynamic or do you have an idea (or a finite list) of what your data columns will be named?

Comment: Ideally it should be dynamic ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at pivoting the data table from:

```
Store  Date  Col1 Col2 Col3 ...
Store1 1/2/12 12   23   34  ...
Store2 1/2/12 23   34   35  ...

Store  Date  Col Value
Store1 1/2/12 Col1 12
Store1 1/2/12 Col2 23
Store1 1/2/12 Col3 34
Store2 1/2/12 Col1 23
Store2 1/2/12 Col2 34
Store2 1/2/12 Col3 35
```

So you can treat the column name as data to be joined/looked up.

Answer (score 2):

From your what I understand of your question, you're looking for the [SQL Server UNPIVOT function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), which takes columns and pivots them into individual rows/values.  Combine that with a join to get your required information from the Lookup table.

To do this in SSIS, you could use the [UNPIVOT Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx)

Comment: Tried this with the Unpivot SSIS task and am getting an error.
I selected StoreID and TxDate as Pas through and Amount as the Destination field name, with Tenders as the name for all the Col values, which is consistent with teh demos that I have seen.
I suspect my issue is due to wanting to pass through the two fields, but I need to do that ??

Comment: I've not worked with the UNPIVOT Transformation myself to be honest but could you not use the Advanced Editor and set some extra Output Columns manually? What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a little confusing. I understand what you are trying to do but not 100% sure where the data is stored. Is this correct?:
You have 2 tables,
1 table has the data you want?
1 table has the value to search the first table for?

If so you want something like:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, ... 
FROM table_1 t1 
    LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.common_field = t2.common_field 
WHERE t2.search_by = 'CRITERIA'
```